# Scale factor of the determinant: I'm blind (SOLVED)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, gaussian-elimination

I have the following matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 8 \\ 3 & 6 & 9 \\ 4 & 7 & 9 \end{pmatrix}$$

I already calculated the determinant with Laplace in two different ways, row and column expansion. Now I was going to perform a Gauss reduction, and then use the scale factor to show the determinant is the same.

By the way, det$(A) = 3$.

Yet after having done Gauss algorithm, the scale factor doesn't add properly. I think I'm blind and I don't see something really obvious...

These are the operations:

- multiply row $2$ ( = $R_2$) by $\frac{1}{3}$

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 8 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 7 & 9 \end{pmatrix}$$

- Computing $2R_2 - R_1$ in the place of $R_2$ and $R_3- 2R_1$ in the place of $R_3$:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 8 \ 0 & -1 & -2 \ 0 & -3 & -7 \end{pmatrix}

- Multiply by $(-1)$ the last two rows

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 8 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3 & 7 \end{pmatrix}$$

- Last: $R_3 - 3R_2$

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 8 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

So the scale factor is

$$d = \frac{1}{3}\cdot (-1) \cdot (-1) = \frac{1}{3}$$

yet $$\text{det}(A) = 2d \rightarrow \frac{2}{3}$$

What I am not seeing?

**SOLVED**

Comment: a) You forgot $2$ (when you replace $R_2$ with $2R_2-R_1$) in your "scale factor" $d.$ b) $\det A=2/d,$ not $2d.$

Comment: When doing $2R_2-R_1\rightarrow R_2$, you’re scaling row two by two.  This must be included in your scale factor.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ohhh damn, it's right! The multiplication of a row by a scalar! I really did not see this for I just computed the "naive" rows substraction without paying attention to the scalars... Thank you!!

Comment: Not only that, but also you multiplied by $d$ instead of dividing.

Comment: From the title I thought this question was going to be about non-visual intuition for why the determinant is a generalization of scaling